# Spring ScopedProxy session Bean JSON exports targetClass details in JSON response

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson, response

When I send a session scoped bean in response it generates the following as details as well:

```
    "accountNonExpired": true,
  "accountNonLocked": true,
  "credentialsNonExpired": true,
  "enabled": true,
  "chfDbqUserLevel": 1,
  "eurDbqUserLevel": 1,
  "frozen": false,
  "targetClass": "com.......models.PxUser",
  "targetSource": {
    "targetBeanName": "scopedTarget.pxUser",
    "targetClass": "com......models.PxUser",
    "beanFactory": {
      "parentBeanFactory": null,
      "beanClassLoader": {
        "parent": {
          "parent": {
            "parent": {
              "parent": null,
              "urls": [
                "file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_92/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar",
                "file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_92/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar",
                "file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_92/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar",
```

How can exclude targetClass details from response?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding @JsonIgnoreProperties("targetClass") for you session managed bean.

Comment: it is a spring @component,  scopedproxymode.targetclass, session. 
I could do 
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"targetClass", "targetSource", "targetObject"})
Which class should be ignored?

Comment: Exactly. Try using this annotation with your @component and let me know if it helps.

Comment: from the json got these three properties and suppressed it, it worked.
If there is no other nicer way, i will mark as accepted.

Comment: Nice to know that my answer helped you..This is the most straightforward solution. You could use JsonMixins and a Jackson module for a more decoupled solution. Take a look at this great tutorial http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization

Comment: To remove all spring enhancements @JsonIgnoreProperties({"targetClass", "targetSource", "targetObject", "advisors", "frozen", "exposeProxy", "preFiltered", "proxiedInterfaces", "proxyTargetClass"})